# Browser cannot find files (exported by webpack) when I enter the URL directly

Tags: css, reactjs, redirect, webpack, react-router

I have a React webpage with the following routes:

```
localhost:8000/
localhost:8000/login
localhost:8000/auth/callback
localhost:8000/about/me
```

My *index.js* displays some buttons so I can visit each of the 4 routes. It works fine. Here's the catch though: when I type in the URL to the *AboutMe* page in the browser's address bar, I get the error below. Same goes for the callback that I want to be redirected to when I use OAuth on the *Login* page.

The error message (here: entering the AboutMe page directly into the address bar):

```
me:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8000/about/woff.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

me:14 GET http://localhost:8000/about/main.bundle.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

**Questions:**

- Does the browser find the *dist/index.html* if I enter the URL of the AboutMe page directly?

  > Aparantly yes, since it tries to load *woff.css* and *bundle.js*. These imports were injected into the HTML by webpack.
- Why does it look for the stylesheet and script in the new path?
- Why does the react router not kick in?

---

Here is my `webpack.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const GoogleFontsPlugin = require('google-fonts-plugin');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/bootstrap/index.tsx',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.less']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
    library: 'my-library-react', // Important
    libraryTarget: 'umd', // Important
    filename: '[name].bundle.min.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|tsx|ts)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader' },
          { loader: 'css-loader' },
          {
            loader: 'less-loader',
            options: {
              modifyVars: {
                hack: `true; @import "${__dirname}/src/theme/custom-theme.less";`
              },
              javascriptEnabled: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 10000
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/bootstrap/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html', // destination
    }),
    new GoogleFontsPlugin('./src/theme/fonts.config.json')
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *webpack.config.js* the following changes must be applied:

```js
// ...

module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '.bundle.js'
    // ...
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: {
      index: '/'
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```